# Enviar datos en Servicio WS SOAP con VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, soap, soapui

Estoy tratando de hacer una macro en VBA en excel para enviar un request por medio de un servicio Web Service SOAP, logré crearlo con el siguiente código confirmando que efectivamente funciona:

```
Sub erp_automatico()
Dim sURL As String
Dim sEnv As String
Dim xmlhtp As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim xmldoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60

sURL = "https://b2b.falabella.com/b2bwsfacopr/ws/adminArchivoService"

sEnv = "<soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" 
xmlns:adm=""http://b2b.falabella.com/schemas/ol/admin-archivo-carga- 
request"">"
sEnv = sEnv & "   <soapenv:Header><wsse:Security 
soapenv:mustUnderstand=""1"" xmlns:wsse=""http://docs.oasis- 
open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd""> 
<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id=""UsernameToken-37"" 
xmlns:wsu=""http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"">"
sEnv = sEnv & "   <wsse:Username>811111111-0|33333333-0</wsse:Username>"
sEnv = sEnv & "   <wsse:Password Type=""http://docs.oasis- open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText"">79521984yusidkfgj21F60A7B5</wsse:Password>"
sEnv = sEnv & "   <wsse:Nonce EncodingType=""http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary"">/ZM4HrHD7nAQFQd+dwvdbw==</wsse:Nonce><wsu:Created>2017-12-11T17:49:15.362Z</wsu:Created></wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security></soapenv:Header>"
sEnv = sEnv & "   <soapenv:Body>"
sEnv = sEnv & "      <adm:admin-archivo-carga-request>"
sEnv = sEnv & "         <adm:files>"
sEnv = sEnv & "            <!--1 or more repetitions:-->"
sEnv = sEnv & "            <adm:file>"
sEnv = sEnv & "               <adm:tipo-archivo>eRP</adm:tipo-archivo>"
sEnv = sEnv & "               <adm:archivo>gjhhgfjg</adm:archivo>"
sEnv = sEnv & "               <adm:extension-archivo>XML</adm:extension-archivo>"
sEnv = sEnv & "            </adm:file>"
sEnv = sEnv & "         </adm:files>"
sEnv = sEnv & "      </adm:admin-archivo-carga-request>"
sEnv = sEnv & "   </soapenv:Body>"
sEnv = sEnv & "</soapenv:Envelope>"

Set xmlhtp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
With xmlhtp
.Open "POST", sURL, False
.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=UTF-8"
.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", ""
.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", "Length"

.send sEnv
Set xmldoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
xmldoc.LoadXML .responseText
Debug.Print xmldoc.XML
End With
Set xmldoc = Nothing
Set xmlhtp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Ahora, en etiqueta **`<adm:archivo>`** del servicio debo enviar un texto XML como el siguiente:

**`<![CDATA[<eRP><ACCION>RP</ACCION><PROVEEDOR>890101279</PROVEEDOR><USUARIO>11111111</USUARIO><RP num="1"><FOLIO>12539296670</FOLIO><GUIA>428385200</GUIA><FACTURA/><CANT_BULTOS>1</CANT_BULTOS><PRODUCTO><PRODUCTO_ROW num="1"><SKU>3470950</SKU><ETIQUETA>428385200</ETIQUETA></PRODUCTO_ROW></PRODUCTO></RP></eRP>]]>`**

pero al colocarlo dentro de la etiqueta, excel me arroja un error de compilación.

Realizando la misma acción en SoapUI el servicio responde correctamente.

Agradezco la ayuda que me puedan dar.

Answer (score 1):

El valor que intentas usar contiene comillas en el interior, tienes que "escapar" las comillas. Para escapar comillas en VBA, tienes que duplicarlas, por ejemplo; si tu texto es: 
"Escape" is the solution
Lo escribirias como:

```
Dim str As String
str = """Escape"" is the solution"
```

Para el caso en question:

```
Dim str As String
str = "<![CDATA[<eRP><ACCION>RP</ACCION><PROVEEDOR>890101279</PROVEEDOR><USUARIO>11111111</USUARIO><RP num=""1""><FOLIO>12539296670</FOLIO><GUIA>428385200</GUIA><FACTURA/><CANT_BULTOS>1</CANT_BULTOS><PRODUCTO><PRODUCTO_ROW num=""1""><SKU>3470950</SKU><ETIQUETA>428385200</ETIQUETA></PRODUCTO_ROW></PRODUCTO></RP></eRP>]]>"
MsgBox (str)
```